# Logical condition / math expression validation

Tags: regex, perl

I want to validate a string, that is containing an expression like

```
isFun && ( isHelpful || isUseful )
```

These expressions can contain operands, binary operators and unary operators:

```
my $unary_operator  = qr/(?:\+|\-|!|not)/;
my $binary_operator = qr/(?:<|>|<=|>=|==|\!\=|<=>|\~\~|\&|\||\^|\&\&|\|\||lt|gt|le|ge|and|or|xor|eq|ne|cmp)/i;
my $operand         = qr/[a-z0-9_]+/i;
```

They are kind of similiar to what you know from perl's condition pattern (for example inside of if statements). The brackets have to be balanced and unary operators can only be used once in a row.

I would like to find a perl compatible regular expression, that makes sure to have a valid logical / mathmatical expression where only the given operators are used and the operands are matching the regex that is given by `$operand`. With recursions, this could be possible in perl. The statement is in infix notation.

My current solution is to parse a tree and perform some iterations, but I want to compress this algorithm into a single regular expression.

For my first try (I still excluded all verbose operands), I used

```
my $re =
qr{
    ( # 1
        ( # 2 operands ...
            $operand
        )
        |
        ( # 3 unary operators with recursion for operand
            (?:$unary_operator(?!\s*$unary_operator)\s*(?1))
        )
        |
        ( # 4 balance brackets
            \(
                \s*(?1)\s*
            \)
        )
        |
        ( # 5 binary operators with recursion for each operand
            (?1)\s*$binary_operator\s*(?1)
        )
    )
}x;
```

...which ends up in infinite recursion. I think the recursion might be caused in using the first (?1) in parenthesis 5.

Is somebody out there with a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for validating your expressions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $unary_operator  = qr/(?:\+|\-|!|not)/;
my $binary_operator = qr/(?:<|>|<=|>=|==|\!\=|<=>|\~\~|\&|\||\^|\&\&|\|\||lt|gt|le|ge|and|or|xor|eq|ne|cmp)/i;
my $operand         = qr/[a-z0-9_]+/i;

my $re =
qr{^
    ( # 1
        \s*
        (?> (?:$unary_operator \s*)* )
        (?:
             \b$operand\b
        |
             \( (?1) \)
        )
        (?:
            \s*
            $binary_operator
            \s*
            (?1)
        )*
        \s*
    )
$}x;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($expr, $status) = split "#", $_, 2;

    if ($expr =~ $re) {
        print "good  $_\n";
    } else {
        print "bad   $_\n";
    }

}

__DATA__
isFun                                    # Good
isFun && isHelpful                       # Good
isFun && isHelpful || isUseful           # Good
isFun && ( isHelpful || isUseful )       # Good
isFun && ( isHelpful || (isUseful) )     # Good
isFun && ( isHelpful || (isUseful )      # Fail - Missing )
not (isFun && (isHelpful || (isBad && isDangerous)))  # Good
isGenuine!isReal                         # Fail
!isGenuine isReal                        # Fail
```

Outputs:

```
good  isFun                                    # Good
good  isFun && isHelpful                       # Good
good  isFun && isHelpful || isUseful           # Good
good  isFun && ( isHelpful || isUseful )       # Good
good  isFun && ( isHelpful || (isUseful) )     # Good
bad   isFun && ( isHelpful || (isUseful )      # Fail - Missing )
good  not (isFun && (isHelpful || (isBad && isDangerous)))  # Good
bad   isGenuine!isReal                         # Fail
bad   !isGenuine isReal                        # Fail
```

Comment: Hey Miller! That was close, but it will return false positive for `isGenuine!isReal` and `!isGenuine isReal`. I think this happens, because of `ne` beeing an operator as part of `isGeniune`. I replaced `ne` (and all other verbose operators) by `\bne\b` in the operator sets to fix that problem, but I'd prefer a solution, that can handle the operator sets given in the question above. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Yeah, that was more a problem with your regex's, but it can be fixed by added a word boundary around the operand:  `\b$operand\b`

Comment: Ok, word boundaries around the operands do obviously make a lot more sense than around the operators! Thank you! `yourAnswer == ( isAwesome && isHelpful )` :D